# Using Swagger annotations to document request body of array type

Tags: java, json, scala, swagger

I have a resource that accepts POST requests with JSON body of array type, for example:

```
[
  { "foo": "bar" },
  { "foo": "baz" },
  ...
]
```

To document non-collection type using Swagger annotations I can do:

```
@ApiImplicitParams(Array(
  new ApiImplicitParam(paramType = "body", dataType = "my.Request", required = true)
))
```

How to do the same for array body type, e.g. `Seq[my.Request]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done by introducing a surrogate trait that extends Java's standard library list:

```
trait ArrayBody extends java.util.List[ArrayElementType]
```

And then in the endpoint annotations:

```
@ApiImplicitParams(Array(
  new ApiImplicitParam(paramType = "body", dataType = "foo.bar.ArrayBody", required = true)
))
```